# Maximum number of subshells in Linux

Tags: linux

What is the maximum amount of subshells spawned in Linux? (is it related to maximum number of processes given by */proc/sys/kernel/pid_max*?

(assuming that)

```
# (file: /bin/a)
echo hello
# if condition would be here
# search if it's needed to spawn next sub-shell
a "arg1" "arg2"
```

The abstract script above does not infinitely spawn new subshells,
only if it's needed, then it returns to it's parent shell. But it's possible such script would have a lot of subshells spawned
as it goes deep.

Comment: There's also a per-user max number of processes. You can see this with `ulimit -u`

Comment: There's no limit specifically for subshells. So only the process limits would limit it.